# Hover moving other elements to the right

Tags: html, css

Whenever my mouse hovers to one of the long `<li>` elements the other elements move to the right.

Here's the fiddle link :

```css
.footer_links{
    margin-top:60px;
    
}

footer .ourServices{

 display: inline-block;
 float:left;
 margin: 0px -10px 0px 77px;
    
}

footer .ourServices ul li,a,h3{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
    list-style: none;
}

footer .ourServices .columns_title{
    text-transform: uppercase
}


footer .ourServices .columns_title{
    margin-bottom:17px;
    font-size:23px;
    font-family:raleway-regular;
    font-weight:lighter;
}
footer .ourServices ul li, h3{
    margin-bottom:8px;
    font-size:12px;
}

footer .ourServices ul li{
    margin-top: 10px;
}

footer ul li:hover{
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-weight:bold;

}
```

```html
<div class="footer_links">
                                    <div class="ourServices">
                                        <h3 class="columns_title">Connect</h3>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>1234 Street Name</li>
                                            <li>Suburb Title</li>
                                            <li>State, Australia 400</li>
                                            <li>Phone:(00) 000 000 000</li>
                                            <li>fax:(00) 000 000 000</li>
                                            <li>info@email.com</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                            
                                    <div class="ourServices">
                                        <h3 class="columns_title">Our Services</h3>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Cotmprehensive geriatric assessment</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Falls, mobility problems</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Incontinence</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Polypharmacy</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Osteoporosis</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Frailty</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                            
                            <div class="ourServices">
                                        <h3 class="columns_title">Explore</h3>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#">Our Doctors</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Treatments</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Appointments</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </div>
```

jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=kdkeI5Hnq6

Comment: that is because you are changing the style of the texts to `bold`.. try adding height and width on your containers as well.

Comment: Please edit your post so the link is clickable and also put the relevant portions of the code into the question.

Comment: @torazaburo OP *cannot* do so, and for good reason: questions must contain a repro *inside* the question itself (for one, to prevent link rot from rendering the question useless), not just a link to jsfiddle. - Please ask for "a repro in the question 'optionally backed by a jsfiddle'" or something similar, when you see posts like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the width of each `div` is being determined by the width of its contents, and the positioning of the other div is determined by the positioning of the `div` beside it. The `bold` hover effect is causing the text within to get wider, which is causing a chain reaction in the positioning of the other elements.

To fix it, set the width of the container so that it won't resize based on its contents:

```
footer .ourServices {
    width: 170px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, much better didn't have to destroy the template haha . Thanks to everyone though! :)))

Answer (score 0):

You Just Set width for your class like this:

```
 footer .ourServices
 {
   width: 150px;
 }
```

Comment: It fix it though. Thanks @4castle if you can recommend something better?

Comment: @nitan I have posted an answer.

Comment: I have wditted my post: Thank You.